# How to use a certificate without the password

Tags: security, certificate

I have an application that uses a digital certificate class 2 to download some files. I know this isn't a good idea but the application handles the input of the password automatically.

Now a new client wants this application but they do not want to give me the password because they're afraid I would be able to do anything with their certificate+password.

Is there any way I could either:

- Use the certificate to download files WITHOUT the need to know the password.

or

- Get a second certificate that would only let me download the files from a certain URL.

Any help regarding these topics will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use the certificate to download files WITHOUT the need to know the password.

Impossible. The password is used for encrypting the private keying material. Since you do not know the password, you don't know the private key, and you cannot use the certificate for authentication.

However, note that password have much less entropy than keys. If your client didn't thought a good password, it could be relatively easy to guess it by brute-force. [This site](http://boredwookie.net/index.php/blog/certificate-password-recovery-tool/) claims that you can do about 30 million of password tries per day. Then, assuming a password with 28 bytes of entropy (i.e. 2^28 combinations), you can guess the password in one or two weeks.

[image: Password entropy]

> Get a second certificate that would only let me download the files from a certain URL.

That part of the question depends on what certificates are accepted by the server...

Comment: Can you give me any pointers on where to look at for types of certificates? If the first option is impossible, I would like to try generating a certificate for a specific URL...

Comment: It works the other way: the server administrator decides which certificates will be authorized. Ask them.